# Rails5: getting a form submission error and confused as to why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, so I'm trying to update an old app by rebuilding it in a seperate Rails 5 app that points to the same database (well not really the --same-- but a clone of that DB)

I've recently tried using a nested form field approach to solve my "create new record" problem for this particular form but got jammed up for some reason....

soooooo...

I've gone back and tried a different approach by building a new event in the controller new action called "add_shift" and assigning each field individually. Then in my "create" using a method called create_shift.

NOTE: this was the technique used in the old app as well so I'm trying to port it over to the newer app...here is the error I am getting

the error

```
Started POST "/assignments" for blah-my-ip at 2021-11-08 06:48:49 -0800
Cannot render console from blah-my-ip! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by AssignmentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "volunteer_task_type_id"=>"41", "roster_id"=>"7", "program_id"=>"9", "set_description"=>["fonso nov8 test"], "set_date"=>["2021-01-05"], "assignment"=>{"start_time(1i)"=>"2021", "start_time(2i)"=>"11", "start_time(3i)"=>"8", "start_time(4i)"=>"08", "start_time(5i)"=>"00", "end_time(1i)"=>"2021", "end_time(2i)"=>"11", "end_time(3i)"=>"8", "end_time(4i)"=>"09", "end_time(5i)"=>"00", "notes"=>"Nov888", "contact_id"=>"166574", "closed"=>"0", "lock_version"=>"0"}, "contact_element_prefix"=>"contact", "commit"=>"Submit"}
  VolunteerTaskType Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "volunteer_task_types".* FROM "volunteer_task_types" WHERE "volunteer_task_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 41], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Roster Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "rosters".* FROM "rosters" WHERE "rosters"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Program Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering assignments/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered assignments/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1202ms (Views: 269.7ms | ActiveRecord: 11.5ms)
```

....below are my controller, models and views related to this form...

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #TODO refactor this line to be very specific

  # GET /assignments or /assignments.json
  def index
     @assignments = Assignment.date_range(params[:start]..params[:end])
  end

  # GET /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /assignments/new
  def new
    add_shift
    # @assignment.volunteer_shift.build
    @my_url = {:action => "create", :id => params[:id]}
  end

  # GET /assignments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /assignments or /assignments.json
  def create
    # @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
    create_shift

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def add_shift   # FIXME: evil brought over from old app
    ve = nil
    if !params["id"].blank?
      ve = VolunteerEvent.find_by_id(params["id"])
    else
      ve = VolunteerEvent.new
    end
    vs = ve.volunteer_shifts.new
    vs.program = Program.find_by_name("intern")
    #    vs.slot_count = 1
    vs.volunteer_event_id = ve.id if ve.id
    vs.volunteer_event = ve
    a = vs.assignments.new
    a.volunteer_shift = vs
    vs.stuck_to_assignment = true
    vs.not_numbered = true
    @assignments = vs.assignments = [a]
    @referer = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
    @my_url = {:action => "create_shift", :id => params[:id]}
    @assignment = a
    # binding.pry
    # render :partial => 'assignments/new'
    # render :partial => 'assignments/edit' #<--original
  end

  def create_shift # FIXME: evil brought over from original code base
    # @fonso = @assignment.inspect
    ve = nil
    # Fixme: building volunteer shifts variable "vs" and associating with assignment
    if !params["id"].blank?
      ve = VolunteerEvent.find(params["id"])
    else
      if params["roster_id"].blank? || params["set_date"].blank?
        ve = VolunteerEvent.new # won't save
      else
        ve = Roster.find_by_id(params["roster_id"]).vol_event_for_date(params["set_date"])
      end
    end
    vs = ve.volunteer_shifts.new
    vs.stuck_to_assignment = true
    vs.not_numbered = true
    #fixme: volunteer shifts variable "vs" and association with assignment end


    # FIXME: vs.attributes=(params["assignment"]["volunteer_shift_attributes"]) # original needs to be rebuilt 4 this system
    h0 = {"volunteer_task_type_id" => params["volunteer_task_type_id"]}
    h1 = {"roster_id" => params["roster_id"]}
    h2 = {"program_id" => params["program_id"]}
    h3 = {"set_description" => params["set_description"]}
    hash_arr = [h0,h1,h2,h3]
    volunteer_shift_attributes = hash_arr.reduce { |acc, h| (acc || {}).merge h }
    vs.attributes = volunteer_shift_attributes
    #fixme: vs.attributes fix end

    #FIXME: building variable - @assignments END
    assignment = vs.assignments.new
    vs = assignment.volunteer_shift
    assignment.attributes = (assignment_params)
    @assignments = [assignment]
    #fixme: building variable - @assignments END

    #FIXME: wtf is it and why is it?
    vs.assignments = [assignment]
    vs.set_values_if_stuck #fixme: <---- drill into this one
    vs.assignments = []
    binding.pry
    @success = assignment.valid? && vs.save #fixme: <--------what was the valid? error here?

    @assignment = assignment #fixme: <-----------------------@assignment is finally built here

    # fixme: the above lines are merging params from one into the other in the old app.
    # fixme: to create the new volunteer_shift.
    if @success
      vs = vs.reload
      @assignment = a = vs.assignments.new
      a.volunteer_shift = vs
      #    a.volunteer_shift_id = vs.id
      a.attributes = (params["assignment"])
      @assignments = vs.assignments = [a]

      if !@success
        vs.destroy
      end
    end
  end


  def update # ported over from old app
    unless params[:assignment]
      redirect_to :action => "index"
      return
    end
    @my_url = {:action => "update", :id => params[:id]}
    last_id = nil
    begin
      @assignments = params[:id].split(",").map{|x| last_id = x; Assignment.find(x)}
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      flash[:jsalert] = "The assignment (##{last_id.to_i.inspect}) seems to have disappeared or never existed. It is possible somebody else has modified or deleted it."
      rt = params[:assignment].delete(:redirect_to)
      redirect_skedj(rt, "")
      return
    end
    lv = params["lock_versions"]
    ac = params["assigned_contacts"] || {}
    @assigned_contacts = []
    @replaced_contacts = []
    ret = true
    @assignments.each do |as|
      as.lock_version = lv[as.id.to_s]
      if as.lock_version_changed?
        as.errors.add("lock_version", "is stale for this assignment, which means it has been edited by somebody else since you opened it, please try again")
        ret = false
      end
      if as.contact_id && as.contact_id.to_s != params[:assignment][:contact_id].to_s
        @assigned_contacts << as.contact
        unless ac[as.contact_id.to_s] && ac[as.contact_id.to_s] == "replace"
          as.errors.add("contact_id", "has been changed, please confirm below that the volunteer who is already assigned to the shift should be removed")
          ret = false
        else
          @replaced_contacts << as.contact_id
        end
      end
    end
    rt = params[:assignment].delete(:redirect_to)

    js_alert = nil

    if ! ret
      @assignment = Assignment.new
      @assignment.volunteer_shift = @assignments.first.volunteer_shift
      @assignment.attributes=(params[:assignment]) # .. ? .delete("volunteer_shift_attributes")
    end

    @assignments.each{|x|
      if ret
        @assignment = x
        bc = x.contact_id
        ret = !!(x.update_attributes(params[:assignment]))
        if bc != x.contact_id and x.first_time_in_area?
          alert = "#{x.contact.display_name} (##{x.contact_id}) has never logged hours for the #{x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_task_type.description} task type. Please remind the volunteer of the requirements for this area."
          if x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event and x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.notes and x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.notes.length > 0
            alert += "\n\nSome suggested notes saved in the database for this event are:\n" + x.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.notes
          end
          js_alert = alert
        end
      end
    }

    if ret && @assignment.contact and not @assignment.contact.is_old_enough?
      msg = "This volunteer is not yet #{Default['minimum_volunteer_age']} years old (based on their saved birthday: #{@assignment.contact.birthday.to_s}).\nPlease remind the volunteer that they must have an adult with them to volunteer."
      if js_alert == nil
        js_alert = msg
      else
        js_alert = msg + "\n\n" + js_alert
      end
    end

    flash[:jsalert] = js_alert if js_alert

    if ret
      flash[:notice] = 'Assignment was successfully updated.'
      redirect_skedj(rt, @assignment.volunteer_shift.date_anchor)
    else
      @referer = rt
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end

  # DELETE /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def destroy
    @assignment.destroy
    # NOTE: comment original out 4 now
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html { redirect_to assignments_url, notice: "Assignment was successfully destroyed." }
    #   format.json { head :no_content }
    # end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_assignment
      @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def assignment_params
      #fixme: ,volunteer_shift_attributes: [:???, :???, :???] <--- insert this below?
            params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :date_range, :set_date, :date, :volunteer_shift_id, :contact_id, :start_time, :end_time, :start, :end, :attendance_type_id, :notes, :call_status_type_id, :closed, :lock_version, :color, :description)
      # params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :redirect_to, :set_date, :date_range, :contact_id, :start_time, :end_time, :start, :end, :attendance_type_id, :notes, :call_status_type_id, :closed, :lock_version, :color, volunteer_shift_attributes: [:volunteer_task_type_id,:roster_id,:program_id,:set_description,:set_date,:id,:destroy])
    end
end
```

Model assignment

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  # attr_accessor :volunteer_event ,:contact_id #why is this volunteer_event and not volunteer_shift???
  belongs_to :volunteer_shift
  has_one :volunteer_task_type, :through => :volunteer_shift, :source => :volunteer_task_type
  belongs_to :contact ,optional: true
  validates_presence_of :volunteer_shift #belongs_to takes care of this now
  validates_associated :volunteer_shift
  belongs_to :attendance_type
  belongs_to :call_status_type
  validates_presence_of :set_date, :if => :volshift_stuck #belongs_to takes care of this now??
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_shift, allow_destroy: true

  delegate :set_date, :set_date=, :to => :volunteer_shift
  delegate :set_description, :set_description=, :to => :volunteer_shift

  has_one :contact_volunteer_task_type_count, lambda{||
    {:conditions => 'contact_volunteer_task_type_counts.contact_id = #{defined?(attributes) ? contact_id : "assignments.contact_id"}', :through => :volunteer_shift, :source => :contact_volunteer_task_type_counts}
  }
  scope :date_range, lambda { |range|
    joins(volunteer_shift: :volunteer_event)
        .where(volunteer_shifts: { volunteer_events: { date: range } })
  }
  scope :is_after_today, lambda {||
    { :conditions => ['(SELECT date FROM volunteer_events WHERE id = (SELECT volunteer_event_id FROM volunteer_shifts WHERE id = assignments.volunteer_shift_id)) > ?', Date.today] }
  }
  scope :on_or_after_today, lambda {||
    { :conditions => ['(SELECT date FROM volunteer_events WHERE id = (SELECT volunteer_event_id FROM volunteer_shifts WHERE id = assignments.volunteer_shift_id)) >= ?', Date.today] }
  }
  scope :not_cancelled, -> { where('(attendance_type_id IS NULL OR attendance_type_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM attendance_types WHERE cancelled = \'t\'))')}
  scope :roster_is_limited_by_program, -> {where("roster_id IN (SELECT id FROM rosters WHERE limit_shift_signup_by_program = 't')").joins(:volunteer_shift)}

  def real_programs
    return [] unless self.volunteer_shift&.roster
    return [] unless self.volunteer_shift.roster.limit_shift_signup_by_program
    self.volunteer_shift.roster.skeds.select{|x| x.category_type == "Program"}.map{|x| x.name}
  end

  attr_accessor :attendance_type_id


# TODO: find all time_range_s methods and either pull out to DRY or give unique names
  def time_range_s
    return "" unless start_time and end_time
    (start_time.strftime("%I:%M") + ' - ' + end_time.strftime("%I:%M")).gsub( ':00', '' ).gsub( ' 0', ' ').gsub( ' - ', '-' ).gsub(/^0/, "")
  end

  def description
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.volunteer_shift.volunteer_event.date.strftime("%D") + " " + self.time_range_s + " " + self.slot_type_desc
  end

  def roster_title
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.volunteer_shift.roster.name
  end

def date
     return unless volunteer_shift
     volunteer_shift.date
   end

  #full calendar uses this method name....see the assignment.json.jbuilder
  def event_date
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.date
  end


  def contact_display
    if self.closed
      "(closed)"
    elsif contact_id.nil?
      return "(available)"
    else
      self.contact.display_name + "(#{self.voltask_count})"
    end
  end

  before_validation :set_values_if_stuck
  def set_values_if_stuck
    return unless (volshift_stuck || volunteer_shift)
    volunteer_shift.set_values_if_stuck(self)
  end

  after_destroy { |record| if record.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment; record.volunteer_shift.destroy; else VolunteerShift.find_by_id(record.volunteer_shift_id).fill_in_available; end}
  after_save {|record| if record.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment; record.volunteer_shift.save; end}
  after_save { |record| VolunteerShift.find_by_id(record.volunteer_shift_id).fill_in_available }

  def volunteer_shift_attributes=(attrs)
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.volunteer_shift.attributes=(attrs) # just pass it up
  end

  def volshift_stuck
    return unless volunteer_shift
    self.volunteer_shift&.stuck_to_assignment
  end

#for fullcalendar
  def all_day_event?
    self.start_time == self.start_time.midnight && self.end_time == self.end_time.midnight ? true : false
  end
end
```

model volunteer_shift

```
class VolunteerShift < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :roster_id
  validates_presence_of :end_time
  validates_presence_of :start_time

  has_many  :assignments

  belongs_to :volunteer_default_shift
  belongs_to :volunteer_task_type
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :volunteer_event
  belongs_to :program

  has_many :contact_volunteer_task_type_counts, :primary_key => 'volunteer_task_type_id', :foreign_key => 'volunteer_task_type_id' #:through => :volunteer_task_type


  def validate
    errors.add("end_time", "is before the start time") unless self.start_time && self.end_time && self.start_time < self.end_time
  end

...

  def set_description
    self.description
  end

  def set_description=(desc)
    self.description=(desc)
  end

  def set_date_set
    @set_date_set
  end

  def set_date=(val)
    @set_date_set = true
    @set_date = val
  end

  def set_date
    @set_date_set ? @set_date : self.volunteer_event.date
  end

  def set_values_if_stuck(assn_in = nil)
    return unless self.stuck_to_assignment #<---it's a boolean in the database
    assn = assn_in || self.assignments.first
    return unless assn
    self.start_time = assn.start_time
    self.end_time = assn.end_time

    return unless self.volunteer_event_id.nil? or self.volunteer_event.description.match(/^Roster #/)
    return unless set_date_set   <----SOMETHING BREAKS HERE on these two lines

    roster = Roster.find_by_id(self.roster_id)
    if roster and !(set_date == nil || set_date == "")
      ve = roster.vol_event_for_date(set_date)
      ve.save! if ve.id.nil?
      self.volunteer_event = ve
      self.volunteer_event_id = ve.id
    else
      if self.volunteer_event.nil?
        self.volunteer_event = VolunteerEvent.new
      end
    end
  end

  def shift_display
    time_range_s + ((!(self.description.nil? or self.description.blank?)) ? (": " + self.description) : "")
  end

  def time_range_s
    return unless self.read_attribute(:start_time) and  self.read_attribute(:end_time)
    (self.my_start_time("%I:%M") + ' - ' + self.my_end_time("%I:%M")).gsub( ':00', '' ).gsub( ' 0', ' ').gsub( ' - ', '-' ).gsub(/^0/, "")
  end

  def my_start_time(format = "%H:%M")
    read_attribute(:start_time).strftime(format)
  end

  def self._parse_time(time)
    Time.mktime(2000, 01, 01, *time.split(":").map(&:to_i))
  end

  def my_start_time=(str)
    write_attribute(:start_time, VolunteerShift._parse_time(str))
  end

  def my_end_time(format = "%H:%M")
    read_attribute(:end_time).strftime(format)
  end

  def my_end_time=(str)
    write_attribute(:end_time, VolunteerShift._parse_time(str))
  end

  def self.range_math(*ranges)
... # have to edit this post down
  end

  def fill_in_available
    return if self.stuck_to_assignment #<-- it's a boolean in the database
    Thread.current['volskedj_fillin_processing'] ||= []
    if Thread.current['volskedj_fillin_processing'].include?(self.id)
      return
    end
    begin
      Thread.current['volskedj_fillin_processing'].push(self.id)
      Assignment.where(volunteer_shift_id: self.id).select{|x| x.contact_id.nil? and !x.closed}.each{|x| x.destroy}
      inputs = [[(self.read_attribute(:start_time)), (self.read_attribute(:end_time))]]
      Assignment.where(volunteer_shift_id: self.id).select{|x| !x.cancelled?}.each{|x|
        inputs.push([(x.start_time), (x.end_time)])
      }
      results = self.class.range_math(*inputs)
      results.each{|x|
        a = Assignment.new
        a.volunteer_shift_id, a.start_time, a.end_time = self.id, x[0], x[1]
        a.volunteer_shift = self
        a.closed = self.volunteer_event.nowalkins
        a.save!
      }
    ensure
      Thread.current['volskedj_fillin_processing'].delete(self.id)
    end
  end

  after_save :fill_in_available

  def date
    self.volunteer_event.date
  end

  def date_display
    self.date.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y').gsub( ' 0', ' ' )
  end

  def date_anchor
    self.date ? self.date.strftime('%Y%m%d') : ''
  end

  def time_shift(val)
    self.start_time += val
    self.end_time += val
  end

  def left_method_name
    [self.volunteer_task_type_id.nil? ? self.volunteer_event.description : self.volunteer_task_type.description, self.slot_number].select{|x| !x.nil?}.join(", ")
  end

  def left_unique_value
    left_method_name
  end

  def description_and_slot
    ((self.volunteer_task_type_id || -1) * 1000) + (self.not_numbered ? 0 : self.slot_number)
  end

  def weekday
    Weekday.find_by_id(self.date.strftime("%w"))
  end
end
```

And the views

_new.html.erb  <----- NOTE this name...this is the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_event">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="col-sm-12 left ">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Assignment - _new.html.erb</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%=@my_url %>
      <%#= render 'assignments/form', assignment: @assignment %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<!--This is NEW action form-->

<%= form_for @assignment, :url => @my_url, remote: true do |f| %>

<!--  #FIXME need a fields_for 4 the volunteer_event-->

  <div class="">
    <div class="modal-body  d-flex">
      <div class="col-sm-8 border-right">
        <section id="location-date-time-notes" class="flex">
          <% if @assignment.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@assignment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this assignment from being saved:</h2>
              <ul>
                <% @assignment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <!--VOLUNTEER SHIFT-->
          <!--TODO: make this a partial under field_for-->
          <%= f.fields_for :volunteer_event do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'assignments/volunteer_shift_fields', vs: builder %>
          <% end %>
          <!--TODO: Volunteer Shift end -->


          <div id="time-row" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <label for="assignment_time" class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Time:
            </label>
            <div class="col- p-2">
              <div class="myStartTime"  id="start_time_<%= @assignment.id %>">
                <%= f.time_select :start_time %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col- p-2"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <div class="myEndTime"  id="end_time_<%= @assignment.id %>">
                <%= f.time_select :end_time %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <label for="assignment_notes" class="col-sm-3 p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Notes:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 p-2">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <span> Notes only get saved if a contact is assigned the shift, and get removed when the contact is removed from the shift.</span>
                <div class="">
                  <%= f.label :notes %>
                  <%= f.text_area :notes %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">

        <!-- Contact Section-->
        <div id="contact_section">
          <% if @assigned_contacts &&  @assigned_contacts.length > 0 %>
            <h2>Previously Assigned Contacts</h2>
            <% @assigned_contacts.each do |c| %>
              <%= label_tag "assigned_contacts[#{c.id}]", "Are you sure you want to remove the currently scheduled volunteer, #{c.display_name} (##{c.id}), from the assignment(s)?" %>
              <%= check_box_tag "assigned_contacts[#{c.id}]", "replace", @replaced_contacts.include?(c.id) %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <input id="contact_element_prefix" name="contact_element_prefix" type="hidden" value="contact">
          <div class="name large flex-row">
            <%= f.label :contact_id %><%= f.text_field :contact_id %>
          </div>

          <div id="display-contact" class="d-flex flex-row">
            <p>_form</p>
            <% if f.object.contact_id %>
              <%= render partial: 'contacts/contact_display', locals: { contact:f.object.contact} %>
            <% else %>
              <div>no contact - _form.html called</div>
              <%#= link_to 'Show Contact', contact_path(f.object.contact_id),  remote: true %>
            <% end %>
          </div>

          <!--    FIXME: replace this logic stack with AJAX-->
          <%#= contact_field("@obj", "contact_id",
        :locals => {:options => {
        :object_name => f.object_name.to_s,
        :field_name => 'contact_id',
        :on_display => 'display_disciplinary_notes(); display_contact_notes();'
        }}
                      ) %>
          <%= f.label :closed, "Is this slot closed?" %>
          <%= f.check_box :closed %>

          <!--Contact Section END-->

          <!--Attendance / Call Status End-->
          <% if f.object.id && f.object.contact_id %>
            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="col-25"><label for="assignment_attendance_type_id">Attendance:</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><%= select(f.object_name,
                                             "attendance_type_id",
                                             AttendanceType.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },
                                             :include_blank => true) %></div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-row">
              <div class="col-25"><label for="assignment_call_status_type_id">Call status:</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><%= select(f.object_name,
                                             "call_status_type_id",
                                             ([["not called yet", ""]] + CallStatusType.all.sort_by(&:id).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }),
                                             :include_blank => false) %></div>

            </div>
          <% end %>
          <!-- Attendance / Call Status End-->

          <!-- LOCK VERSION-->
          <div class="flex-row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <%= f.label :lock_version %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <%= f.number_field :lock_version %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- LOCK end-->
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="edit_icons d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">

        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <%#= link_to '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit'.html_safe, edit_assignment_path,  remote: true%>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= f.submit "Submit" %></button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_volunteer_shift_fields.html.erb

```
<!--<div class="name large flex-row">-->
  <%#= vs.label :volunteer_shift %>
<!--</div>-->
<div id="volunteer_shift" class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 p-2">
    <div id="volunteer_shift" class="text-right">
      <!-- old if: if class is assignment show volunteer shift else show default shift -->
      <!--  we need default shift here...NO assignment is attached-->
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :volunteer_task_type_id %>
        <%= select_tag 'volunteer_task_type_id', options_from_collection_for_select([VolunteerTaskType.new(:description => ""),  VolunteerTaskType.instantiables.effective_on(Date.today)].flatten, "id", "description")  %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :roster_id %>
        <%= select_tag 'roster_id', options_from_collection_for_select([Roster.new(:name => ""), Roster.all].flatten, "id", "name") %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :program_id %>
        <%= select_tag 'program_id', options_from_collection_for_select([Program.new(:name => ""), Program.where(:volunteer => true)].flatten, "id", "name")%>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :set_description %>
        <%= text_field(:set_description, nil) %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :set_date, "Date" %>
        <%= text_field(:set_date, nil) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

assignments/new.html.erb

```
Why is it coming here????
I just want the modal "_new.html.erb" to disapear after the form post but rails is sending me here. And I am confused as to why (something simple I'm sure)

<%= render 'form_old', assignment: @assignment %> <---this old form no longer exist
<!--       
<%= link_to 'Back', assignments_path %>
```

volunteer_shift method set_values_if_stuck (see above also)

```
  def set_values_if_stuck(assn_in = nil)
...
    return unless self.volunteer_event_id.nil? or self.volunteer_event.description.match(/^Roster #/)
    binding.pry
    return unless set_date_set #fixme:<--- pry me

    roster = Roster.find_by_id(self.roster_id)
...
  end
```

Comment: To clarify the reason why this question was closed, it's because it contains ***way*** too much code for a simple problem. You need to create a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal* here) that reproduces your problem. If you are still having this problem and need an answer, please use the [edit] link to update your question, following the above-linked guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat straightforward to me if I'm not mistaken your question as to "why _new is rendered".

```
  def create
    # @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
    create_shift

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here, whatever happens in `create_shift` method, `@assignment` is being saved; if successfully, then render the `:show` page, if not, `:new` page, which by default `_new.html.erb` in this code.

As to "why the save fails", you could print or use one of those pry gems to see `@assignment.errors` right before `@assignment.save`.